# How would you transfer data between components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I recently learned a bit about react and I'm confused about how I would transfer data between two components.

Currently, I have 2 functions implemented as such:

I have topbar.tsx which shows the topbar information, such as showing some button to open the sidebar (which is my next function).

```js
import Sidebar from './sidebar'

export default topbar(props) {
   return (
       <Drawer
           open={isOpen}
           onclose={anotherfunction}>
           <Sidebar />
       </Drawer>
   )
}
```

I also have sidebar.tsx which contains the implementation of sidebar. (This is, if I understand react terminology correctly, the child).

```js
import CloseButton from 'react-bootstrap/CloseButton';

export default Sidebar() {
    return (
        <CloseButton />
    )
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that, since the topbar is the function that controls the opening and closing of the sidebar, however, I want a close button to appear on my sidebar and do exactly as is said. How would I be able to transfer state information between these two files such that I can open sidebar and close it with the button in sidebar.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You elevate your state to the parent component, and pass event handler functions through.

For instance:

```
// Holds state about the drawer, and passes functions to mamange that state as props.
function Topbar() {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
        <Drawer isOpen={isOpen}>
            <Sidebar onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} />
        </Drawer>
   )
}

// Drawer will show it's children if open.
function Drawer({ isOpen, children }: { isOpen: boolean, children: React.ReactNode }) {
    if (!isOpen) return null
    return <div>{children}</div>
}

// Sidebar will send onClose to the button's onClick
function Sidebar({onClose}: { onClose: () => void }) {
    return (
        <CloseButton onClick={onClose} />
    )
}

// Close button doesn't care what happens on click, it just reports the click
function CloseButton({onClick}: { onClick: () => void }) {
    return <div onClick={onClick} />
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXA9L3AASEADYATQnELlKcFACMI+eDAAWVMVBQB3JFGwoAdmLhgUhYpLr5DGYBEOSYEOCBRvDAcypqKUmVTmpoxghAB0XNa2MPaGcAAqEGDyKFAAFACUuFxwuXBoDtJwANrAhADyYEiG2MQwAJIVVYYAunAAvATEZBRIaXQoIsQZOXnsMPhQcWmjeXkAPAAiWrpQcGWV1e04G83UAHyzc8fzJMBiSClrDgDCIhDE25kd+1JIDU3V-YPDtLyHxwWvGWOj0ANyI2oPH4cBBqzg2mAIhEUlUEG06xgLEkaFUSM01XWdDgSWqESidgcsJWejSeF21WwuPx7Di1AAXLh1p9DJzFKJUDV8njxKzOch0DAwhKMAA5CAXGhZHBHYDEtIAQgZhiy40mcUM+GRRz1Uzg8zEwAAbvscMzRdVqPNeJabVwoXwBGcLlcEUiUcRjCTDHcHj4XGoqPJlM5DNjg3dgGgANaRGyUuLey6pOm3e7EDlcvNhznPdqvK0Qc5K7JzU3TI5zeah4gAIRjVLzSeT22LBbg-yOkOhAhbUY7cTEECQhDj8DQqSo2lUfhXYGakipaBE3ewwHgACsiPB2JBYE51Pkdym09FYnAx+2YLHcyHr8nC3guynS1ly3BK2rahlRNd59XNV0E3fXs327P5DmoIA)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, rename topbar to Topbar. Otherwise you can't render your component.

For your question, you can pass the props directly to Sidebar component too.

```
export default Topbar(props) {
       return (
           <Drawer
               open={isOpen}
               onclose={anotherfunction}>
               <Sidebar open={isOpen}
               onclose={anotherfunction}/>
           </Drawer>
       )
    }
```